# rename files in a folder then move them to another folder

Tags: python, file-rename

Ive got a bunch of files in a folder all with the same extension:

[movie] Happy feet 2021-04-01 22-00-00.avi
[movie] Dogs Life 2021-06-01 22-03-50.avi
etc
would like to rename the start and end to:
Happy feet.avi
Dogs Life.avi
etc

Here is what I have so far:

```
import shutil
import os

source_dir = r"C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testsource"
target_dir = r"C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testdest"
data = os.listdir(source_dir)

print(data)

new_data = [file[8:].split(' 2021')[0] + '.txt' for file in data]

print(new_data)


for file in data:
    os.replace(data, [file[8:].split(' 2021')[0] + '.txt')


for file_name in data:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```

Im having trouble with the os.rename() part after I printed it out.

Comment: What happens? Does it give you an error message, does it not rename the files right (if so, what does it rename them to?), does it just do nothing? You need to give us some more information if we're going to be able to help....

Comment: filename, fileextension = os.path.splitext(filename.fileextension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (tested):

```
from glob import glob
import re
import shutil
import os

src = "C:/Users/ED/Desktop/testsource"
dst = "C:/Users/ED/Desktop/testdest"

for f in glob(f"{src}/**"):
    fn = os.path.basename(f) 
    new_fn = re.sub(r"^\[.*?\](.*?) \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\..*?)$", r"\1\2", fn).strip()
    shutil.move(f, f"{dst}/{new_fn}")
```

For python 2:

```
for f in glob(src+"/**"):
    fn = os.path.basename(f) 
    new_fn = re.sub(r"^\[.*?\](.*?) \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\..*?)$", r"\1\2", fn).strip()
    shutil.move(f, dst+"/"+new_fn)
```

Comment: i'm getting a syntax error for 'for f in glob(f"{src}/**"):'

Comment: You need python >= 3.6 to use f strings.

Comment: im using python 2

Comment: Check the python2 version.

Comment: I must be missing something here. The shutil.move is working, the files are all moved from the source to the destination and overwritten if they already exist. Although the filenames remain unchanged. [Movie] Happy Feet 2021-02-01 22-00-04.avi should now be Happy Feet.avi

Comment: Either the folders are wrong or you aren't using my answer's code.

Comment: I'm using your exact code, the folders must be correct because the files are being moved just not changed in any way.

Comment: my issue is that the timestamp on my file was not exactly the same as the way you had it. My fault all resolved now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using r"foobar" I don't think you have to escape the \s, do you?

So it should be

```
source_dir = r"C:\Users\ED\Desktop\testsource"
target_dir = r"C:\Users\ED\Desktop\testdest"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some issues with the code.

In the `for` loop for `os.replace()`, you are passing the entire list of `data` as src which is `['Dogs Life 2021-06-01 22-03-50.avi', '2021-04-01 22-00-00.avi']`

Instead what I did is use `file` in the loop.

Also with the statement `os.replace(data, [file[8:].split(' 2021')[0] + '.txt')` your variables inside `os.replace()` would be a list item, so I changed it string.

One last thing is that you need to use the full file path in the `os.move()` unless the files are in the current working directory

I didn't touch the `shutil.move()` function. Let me know if this works.

```
import shutil
import os

source_dir = r"C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testsource"
target_dir = r"C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testdest"
data = os.listdir(source_dir)

print(data)

new_data = [file[8:].split(' 2021')[0] + '.txt' for file in data]

print(new_data)


for file in data:

    os.replace('C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testsource\\'+str(file), 'C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testsource\\'+str(file[8:].split(' 2021')[0] + '.txt'), src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)
```

Comment: hi there, Im getting an attributes error for the os.replace() line

Comment: I tested it again. It works perfectly for me. The files are renamed as Happy feet and Dog life. I see that you have mentioned that you are using Python 2. I am using Python 3.8 and on a Mac. I think it could be something to do with the str(file) inside replace. Not 100% sure.